# How toEliminate Google from S8+

Tags: applications, security

How do I get Google completely off of my Galaxy S8+.

Comment: You mean the whole Gapps?

Comment: Yes, all links/connections.

Comment: You can disable most of them in settings>application manger>[app name]>disable/uninstall. Fully removing them would most probably require root

Comment: Or a custom ROM. My articles on that topic are not that fresh anymore (being from 2015), but for a raw idea, check my series on [Android without Google](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google).

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings->app settings and select desired app in that menu you can disable the updates and it will still be installed but not executable until you enable it again, the size will reduce since it will keep an executable APK to install updates